# Using multiple versions of Ubuntu on same PC

Tags: 16.04

Could I work with both versions of Ubuntu LTS? it looks like the [Robot Operating System](https://wiki.ros.org/) ('ROS') prefers the older version, I installed the newer, but I would like to switch to the older.

Comment: There is no such thing as Ubuntu versions 16 or 18 ;-) Ubuntu 16.04 is not "Ubuntu 16".

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I have found that ROS works very well with Ubuntu 18.04. If you are having *specific* problems with ROS software, please edit your question to discuss them.

Comment: I dual boot on this pc, it has 18.04 LTS (latest supported LTS) & 20.04 LTS (development release which I bump about a week after release time).  I've another test system that has 4 systems (3 ubuntu + 1 debian), another with 6.  They're all just call dual-booting (*more than 1 OS*), and I select at boot-up time which I'll use. I cannot use them all at the same time though. as I reboot to select another.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can 'dual-boot' Ubuntu, have both versions *XX.XX* and *YY.YY* installed on the same PC. This even includes the officially supported 'flavours' http://ubuntu.com/download/flavours  of Ubuntu with alternate Desktop Environments.

Versions of Ubuntu which *we* support here are 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS, and 19.10 as per http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic . Flavours which we support are 18.04 and 19.10  (flavours have a shorter support life.)

Install the first Ubuntu version, following the instructions at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 .

Then install the second Ubuntu version, also following those instructions. However, when you get to step [6 Allocate Drive Space](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#6-allocate-drive-space), choose *Something else*.

Take space from your primary partition where you installed the first version into, and create a second primary partition for the second version.

Do not share the /home partition between versions. If you want to have shared space on the drive where you can access files from either version, make a dedicate partition for that purpose.

After installation of the second version completes, you will have the choice to choose either version to boot with from the [GRUB menu](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html).

If you want to have both running at the same time and switch without rebooting, that's called [virtualization](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/virtualization.html), and Ubuntu supports several versions of that as well.